time series squared forecast evaluation
I have a time series with very weak autocorrelations- mostly unforecastable. However, its squared values have stronger autocorrelations. Something like this:
idx = pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2023-12-31')
y = pd.DataFrame(index= idx, data=[0]*len(idx))
for t, i in enumerate(idx):
    if t>1:
        y.loc[i] = np.sign(np.random.random_integers(-500000,500000))*(0.01*y.loc[idx[t-1]]+0.005*y.loc[idx[t-2]]) + np.random.randn()

Given the forecastability of squared values, I am using a simple EWMA to forecast them.
I am evaluating the quality of the forecasts by measuring how far away was my forecast squared move vs realized on full sample average and on rolling basis. In addition, I am looking at how big the outliers are.
Upon evaluation of the forecasts for different lookback windows of the EWMA sample, I am observing some behavior which is not very intuitive to me:
roll_window = 60
eval = {}
for com in range(1,100):
    sq_fcst = (y ** 2).ewm(com).mean().shift(1)
    x = ((y**2) / sq_fcst).replace(-np.inf, np.nan).replace(np.inf, np.nan)
    roll_x = np.sqrt((x).rolling(roll_window).mean())
    full_dev = np.sqrt((x).mean())[0]-1
    rolling_dev = np.sqrt(((roll_x - 1)**2).mean()[0])
    outlier = np.percentile(x.abs().dropna().values, 99)

    eval[com] = {'full_dev': full_dev, 'rolling_dev': rolling_dev, 'outlier': outlier}

pd.DataFrame(eval).T.plot(secondary_y = 'outlier')


Here you can see that rolling deviations have a minima around com=10, but then start increasing.
full_dev and outliers do keep on decreasing however.
I think full sample deviation is expected to keep on decreasing by going closer to full sample squared mean as my forecasts , since mean minimized the squared deviation. However, I am not sure why the rolling version would have a minima earlier, and why the outliers would keep on decreasing.

I don't speak Python, but when trying to understand your script for generating data, I do not see that you would be creating autocorrelation in squared values. Regarding your questions, you have a single simulation, right? If you try some more of them, is the same behavior observed?

Hi yes, the behavior is pretty consistent. The autocorrelation is squared values is coming from the autocorrelation param. There is a random sign attached to it which kills the AR in raw values, but not is squared values
